# Expand mysql memory

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import data base, that is more than 128 MB limit, to mysql on XAMMP machine. How can I expand the mysql memory on XAMMP?

Comment: Which memory limit you are hitting exactly? Could you please post the exact error / warning message indicating you hit the limit?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using PHPMyAdmin, you can't - that's a hard limit.

To do it via PHPMyAdmin, you need to split your import files up and run them separately

Alternatively, use a different MySQL client, like the [`mysql` command line client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html) that comes as part of XAMPP, and allows you to run scripts directly.

The `mysql` command allows you to connect to the database using the client, and then run the script from there, like this:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql.exe -u root

mysql> source C:/mysqlscripts/import.sql;
```

*Note the forward slashes in the file path*

Or, you can run it on the windows commandline with the file as a parameter, as described in the documentation.